# Scala - Count a specific Charecter in a String (in a functional style)

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I can count a specific string with the below code

```
 var count = 0
for (i <- "HelloWorldHHHH") {
if (i == 'H') {
  count = count + 1
}
println(count)
```

or use builtins like

```
"HelloWorldHHHH".count(_ == 'H')
```

can someone help me to write the same functionality using pure functional way

I tried the below, but not sure where i am going wrong

```
val count1 = "Hello".foldLeft(0)((x,_) match { case k if(k == 'h') => x +1})
```

the last code has some errors, can someone help me to fix the error or give the correct solution

Comment: change it to `val count1 = "Hello".foldLeft(0) { case (acc, char) => if (char == 'l') acc + 1 else acc }`

Comment: Thanks.. I understand, what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"HelloWorldHHHH".count(_ == 'H')` is already in pure functional style, and it seems the preferred option to me since it is very short and readable.

More options:

**folding**:

```
"HelloWorldHHHH".foldLeft(0){case(count, char) => if (char == 'H') count + 1 else count }
```

**summing after a for-comprehension**. notice that you can use a guard (if):

```
val hs = for {
  i <- "HelloWorldHHHH"
  if i == 'H'
} yield 1
hs.sum
```

**collecting**:

```
"HelloWorldHHHH".collect{ case 'H' => 1 }.sum
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you actually want to do this in production code, I suggest to use the stdlib `count` method:

```
"HelloWorldHHHH".count(_ == 'H')
```

For learning purposes you can roll your own with `foldLeft`:

```
"HelloWorldHHHH".foldLeft(0) { case (sum, char) =>
  if (char == 'H') sum + 1 else sum
}
```

Comment: Thank you Gabriele

Answer (score 1):

You can drop the if and just insert your character in the case block

```
"Hello".foldLeft(0) {(acc,c) => c match {
    case 'l' => acc + 1
    case _ => acc
  }
}
```